# Is a junction box required in my situation?

Tags: electrical, lighting, junction-box

I’m moving my vanity light fixture (*from where it was on the left to the hole on the right*), and the cable is just barely too short to reach the new location (*in particular the ground wire*).

I’m thinking the solution is to install a junction box between the two holes to connect a new cable (*luckily the fixture will hide it*).

I just wanted to double check that this is the best course of action.

[image]

Comment: Do you have attic access?

Comment: @Matthew I *think* I could get to the attic here, but won't be easy.  Why?

Comment: Because you can make a junction in a accessible attic, then you don't need visible plates in the room. You can even do that from inside the room if you can work through the drywall hole before patching. As long as it's accessible without demolition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must use a junction box to make a splice and also remember that you cannot "bury" that box.  Its cover must be accessible.

Comment: Place the junction box 6" to 8" above the old hole and patch the old hole after the new wire is run.

Comment: @jwh20, it’s still considered accessible if it’s behind the fixture, right? Ie I’ll put a panel cover rather than drywall over it, it will just be behind the fixture so not visible unless the fixture is removed. Thanks!!

Comment: @alaska man why above the old hole? I’m hoping to hide it behind the fixture so as to not look weird. Thanks!

Comment: @aknodt - Because as jwh20 pointed out it needs to be accessible. You may know it is there but someone down the line may not. Perhaps it is not against code, i do not know, but it is not intuitive to someone who does not know. What is accessible?

Comment: @AlaskaMan, I was thinking that if someone is troubleshooting electrical in this area, then one step would be removing the fixture, at which point they'd find the junction box. So whenever it needed to be accessible, it would be.  But please lmk if I'm missing some big issue with this!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- Install a single-gang new-work box<sup>1</sup> in the rectangular hole to the left.
- Run a wire behind the wall to the new hole on the right.
- Make the junction on the left
- Wire up the new fixture on the appropriate box in the hole on the right
- Put a blank cover plate<sup>2</sup> on the box on the left
- The fixture itself should act as the cover for the hole on

---

<sup>1</sup>Use a new-work box similar to this:
[image]
<sup>Image courtesy of Lowes.com, no endorsement of vendor or brand intended or implied</sup>
Because you can nail straight through that flange on the left into the stud in the hole on the left. Any sort of flange-mounted box will work just fine, this is simply an example. You do *not* want a new-work box that has 2 nails through the side - there won't be room to swing a hammer at them.

<sup>2</sup>Use a blanking plate like this:
[image]
<sup>Image from Lowes.com, disclaimer, disclaimer, disclaimer</sup>
I chose a metal one because it was more visible in the image, but you can use any color or material you choose. You can even paint/wallpaper the cover plate to match the rest of the wall. I picked a duplex cover plate since if you use the right-hand set of screws to hold it on to the box, it should cover both sides of the hole. You may, depending on the size of that rectangular hole, need to use a triple-gang blank cover plate.

Comment: thanks for your answer!  Good to know about the flange boxes.  I'm really hoping to be able to hide this behind the fixture - I should have been more clear in my post that the fixture goes from the right of the image to just left of where my fingers are, and so I'd like to put the box there where my fingers are.  That way it will be hidden normally but obvious if anyone is doing electrical work in the area and removes the fixture.  But please lmk if there's some reason that's a bad idea.  Thanks!